# Using git-svn for an already checked out svn repository

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I have checked out an svn repository of an open source project. Now I have made some custom changes and I would like to store these changes in a git repository.

As far as I have understood, this can be accomplished with git-svn. However, as I have already checked out the svn and modified my working copy, is it still possible to start with git-svn here?

All resources about git-svn that I have found start with a clone/checkout of the svn.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Copy your modifications away, do the clone checkout as suggested, copy back and then commit. Just don't forget to gitignore .svn directories in addition to any generated files you would normally ignore

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to do the clone/checkout of the SVN repository as you mentioned.  Your local copy of the SVN repo doesn't contain the history information you're going to want in your git repo later.  If you want to apply your changes only in your new git repo, you can do that.  Just make up a patch, create the git repository, and then apply the patch there.